# how to add a new security role to Odoo POS?

Tags: python, python-3.x, security, odoo

i'am new at odoo and i'm asking for help

how to make a new security role for cashier all i need to him is open a POS session and close it, nothing else.

how that can be done ?

i have a moedel already and i have it's roles i need to add a role to the new user to be a cashier just open pos session and close it

```
    <record id="auto_cashir" model="res.groups">
        <field name="name">cashier</field>
        <field name="category_id" ref="base.module_category_point_of_sale"/>
        <field name="implied_ids" eval="[(4, ref('group_pos_user')), (4, ref('stock.group_stock_user'))]"/>
        <field name="users" eval="[(4, ref('base.user_root'))]"/>
    </record>
```

i need to be a role under my model security roles in user form to select the cashir role

Answer (score 1):

A PoS session is opened by a method named `open_session_cb` that belong to the `pos.config` model (`<path_to_v12>/addons/point_of_sale/models/pos_config.py`), so your question translates to how to allow to this particular user permission to only that specific method?

IMHO that cannot be done due to the way Odoo security is designed (see https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/reference/security.html). That is, Odoo can restrict access to models, records, and fields... but not to methods.

The closest you can get is to create an internal user with no application permissions except for the User level for the Point of Sale. To achieve it just make sure the user belongs to the `point_of_sale.group_pos_user` group.